# Wordpress images won't change url to https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mixed-content

Hellos.

I have a website with wordpress and i've just installed a SSL certificate (Let's ecrypt) but i ended up getting a lot of mixed content errors coming fom the images. I've accessed the database and manually changed the urls of all the images to https, however i am still getting the same errors and when i access the gallery in wordpress the images url still point to http.

Any idea why this is happening?

I've also redirected the traffic using the following rule in .htaccess:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

I went to the wordpress database and  in the 'wp_options' table  i've changed the 'home' and 'siteurl' urls to https.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a plugging for this:

[ssl-insecure-content-fixer](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/)